# Prevent hot reload from clearing variable state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a new vue3 project with vite set up.

**my-file.ts:**

```
export const items = ref<string[]>([])
export async function loadItems() {
  items.value = await axios.get(...)
}
```

I run `loadItems()` when the app starts, works fine. But if hot reload triggers from a change, `my-file.ts` is reloaded and `items` becomes empty.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: where do you call ```loadItems()``` in your code ?

Comment: Let's say main.ts, but even if I only import the file from a component, it gets reloaded

Comment: @Johan on hot reload, its state is reset. I think one possible solution is to store the items array in state and then reuse it on hot reload.

Comment: to be honest, your code is kind of doesn't make any sense to me. I've never seen a local state ```ref``` variable being exported like that

Comment: @cantdocpp Because it's global state, explained in the docs

Comment: @RohìtJíndal hmm, in state where?

Comment: @Johan in `vuex` or `pinia` store.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal the end result would be the same, unless it utilizes localstorage, which is kind of a workaround rather than a fix to my question...

Comment: @Johan If you are reloading the browser tab itself, then yeah store will also not work as it will reset on app re-render. In that case HTML5 web storage API will only be helpful (localStorage or sessionStorage).

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I'm not reloading the tab, but HMR will clear a local variable regarless if I or pinia creates it

Comment: The way HMR works is specific to your setup, and the way global store works is specific to your case. Generally there's no such problem in Vue CLI and Vite-based setups. On the opposite, you'd need to do extra actions to get a fresh copy of a store without page reload if necessary. This is how it's supposed to work, https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-akewvm , you may notice that the store stays the same when Hello is resaved . Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.